# NullPointerException when transferring String between two GUI class

Tags: java, swing

I have a table and that it is my `editButton` action method:

```
    public void editAction() {
    if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        String oldFName = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
        String oldLName = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
        String oldGender = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
        System.out.println(oldFName);  // prints correctly
        System.out.println(oldLName);  // prints correctly
        System.out.println(oldGender);  // prints correctly

        AddUserDialog userDialog = new AddUserDialog(this, oldFName, oldLName, oldGender);
    } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select A Row");
}
```

My AddUserDialog Class:

```
    public AddUserDialog(JFrame owner, String oldFname, String oldLname, String oldGender) {
    super(owner, "Edit User Information", true);
    fNameTf.setText(oldFname);     // First name text field
    lNameTf.setText(oldLname);     // Last name text field
    if (oldGender.equals("Male")) maleRb.setSelected(true);  //Male radio Button
    else femaleRb.setSelected(true);                   //Female radio Button

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(400, 100);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}
...
}
```

Now, When i select a row and click to edit button, old first name and old last name and old gender prints correctly on my console , But My IDE say that exception is here:

```
fNameTf.setText(oldFname);       // why is Null here?!
```

**Update**
Second way:

```
    public void editAction() {
    if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        String oldFName = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
        String oldLName = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
        String oldGender = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString();
        System.out.println(oldFName);  // prints correctly
        System.out.println(oldLName);  // prints correctly
        System.out.println(oldGender);  // prints correctly
        AddUserDialog userDialog = null;

        userDialog.setfName(oldFName);  // Why is null here?!
        userDialog.setlName(oldLName);
        userDialog.setGender(oldGender);
        userDialog = new AddUserDialog(this, userDialog.getfName(), userDialog.getlName(), userDialog.getGender());

    } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select A Row");
}
```

Now NullPointerException is here:

```
userDialog.setfName(oldFName);
```

How solve this?

Comment: Where are you initializing `fNameTf`? It doesn't seem to be an argument. (Same goes from `lNameTf`.)

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, Problem was that.

Comment: You set `userDialog` to null on the line right before. Remove the line where you're getting the new NPE, and the three lines below it, and just do `userDialog = new AddUserDialog(this, oldFName, oldLname, oldGender)`, since that seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Could the second NPE be coming from lower in the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fNameTf` is `null` in `AddUserDialog` constructor. You are not initializing the `fNameTf`

EDIT:

```
AddUserDialog userDialog = new AddUserDialog(this, userDialog.getfName(), userDialog.getlName(), userDialog.getGender());

userDialog.setfName(oldFName);
```

Comment: If i don't initialize to `null`, IDE take Error to initialize it

Comment: See the edit I have made you need to create object before using it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this line can throw an NPE, is it `fNameTf` is null since it's the only "dereference" on the line:

```
fNameTf.setText(oldFname);
```

If this gets an NPE on the `setfName` call, it probably means the updated code is not actually being run - that is the most common cause of such confusion in my experience.  Try performing a clean and then build.  Also make sure the updated code is the code being executed (perhaps put in a print statement or the like to prove it).

```
    AddUserDialog userDialog = null;
    userDialog = new AddUserDialog(this, userDialog.getfName(), userDialog.getlName(), userDialog.getGender());
    userDialog.setfName(oldFName);  // Why is null here?!
```